# Kiwi (New Zealand) Pronunciation of "Moscow"

Tags: pronunciation, dialects

So I was watching some Flight of the Conchords just a moment ago (classic), and they're from New Zealand. In one of their songs, they said "Moscow". I'd assumed that Kiwis would say it "Mos-co" (like "to and fro") as us Brits do, but they said it "Mos-cow" like the Americans do. Is this standard for those from NZ, or is this maybe because they're doing an American show (on HBO) and their primary audience is the US?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I, being a Kiwi, think I use both. With a preference towards Mos-cow.

Comment: Interesting. Would you suggest that, in general, when there are small differences between the British and American English, you go with the American (since that's more the "global language")?

Comment: Yes. Probably based on TV's influence. Often I would switch between both, interchangeably. I checked with my wife, and she says she is the same.

Comment: When it is pronunciation only. And when they sound similar. Jam is still jam, not jelly. Scones are not biscuits.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it might also be due to TV influence. Interesting. Thanks very much for your answer! :)